# Equal contributions for authors

Tags: overleaf, revtex, author

I am using the Revtex4.2 package (for a PRL paper) and I want to add equal contribution for the first 2 authors. This can be done as seen for example in this recent PRL paper:

[image]

But I can't seem to find a way to do it. I want to have something of the form:

```
author1^{1,*}, author2^{2,*}
```

where 1 and 2 would correspond to the affiliation and * to the "Equal contribution".
However, by default Revtex doesn't seem to allow me to assign the same symbol to 2 different authors. And if I place the "*" by hand as:

```
\author{author1^$*$}
```

and define:

```
\def\thefootnote{*}\footnotetext{These authors contributed equally to this work}
```

I end up with this:

author1^{ * ,1}, author2^{ * ,2}
which is in the wrong order.

How can I do the same thing as in the picture above? Thank you!